# Is there a correct way to implement partial validations for different parts of one form in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel

I'm working on a project in Laravel that consists of about 100 fields that are distributed over 5 individual pages and forms for those pages. A user is able to save their information even if the required fields aren't filled out yet (although they cannot submit the entire form until all of the required fields are filled out).

What I'd like to do is have something like a "soft" validation per page, that doesn't prevent the model from being saved to the database, but simply has a visual indicator of whether the page is complete.

What I have done so far is implement a `$rules` array for each page, e.g.

```
//in Application model
public static $page_1_rules = array(
            'has_previously_attended' => 'required',
            'degree_status' => 'required',
            'date_of_birth' => 'size:10',
            ...

public static $page_2_rules = array(
            'high_school_start_date' => 'required_if:degree_status,new|size:10',
            'previous_college_1_start_date' => 'required_if:degree_status,transfer|size:10',
            ...
```

Is it possible (or even a good idea) to run validation against the model itself, rather than the `Input::all()` via something like

```
//also in Application model

public static function page1IsComplete($application) 
{
    $validator = Validator::make(/*[get all of the $application's values]*/, Application::$page_1_rules);

    return !$validator->fails();
}
```

My instincts tell me this isn't quite the best way to do it, but I'm not sure if there are some additional features of Laravel I'm unaware of that are more primed for something like this.

Comment: This sounds like it would be well suited to client-side validation, i.e. having the invalid fields marked as such even before the form is submitted. You should *always* have server-side validation (Laravel's or your own custom stuff) but having client-side as a first step is a good place to start. Also, having `required` as a validation on this type of partial-validation seems like backwards thinking: If you can save the field even without it being completely valid, why does it need to be required?

Comment: So in regards to the `required` fields, for something like an open-ended short answer, a user might only fill out a few at a time, and need to come back later to fill out the others. While all of them are required for that page, they still should be able to save the form. What I'm looking for is some sort of flag I guess that looks at one set of validation rules to determine whether the form is complete or not, and uses another set of basic validation rules before saving it to the database.

Comment: I agree, a user shouldn't have any restriction to saving a form, valid or not. That being said, if you have the `required` rule set on a page, the user may not be able to save the form, as they might not have filled in that required field. It's hard to say with this kind of question, as I don't know how your pages work (tabs on the same `page.php`, `page1.php->page2.php->page3.php...`, etc etc)

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion on the client side. Thank you for that. And the pages are their own individual files, `page1.php`, `page2.php`, etc.

Comment: No problem. With that method though, you would have to post the page to "save" it, which would require logic to determine if it was a "save" or a "submit" (or whatever you call a finished form). So, my suggestion, validate the content of the fields being saved (phone, email, regex, date, etc) but don't use `required` unless it's the final submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have implement something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

$step_first = $this->validate_step_1($request);
if($step_first == "true")
// do soft save


$step_second = $this->validate_step_2($request);
if($step_second == "true")
// do actual save

}

    public function validate_step_1(Request $request) {

        // soft validations
        $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'email',
            'company_name' => 'min:2'

        ]);

        if ($v->fails()) {

        return false;

        } else {
        return true;
        }
   }

    public function validate_step_2(Request $request) {

        // some serious validations
        $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'email',
            'company_name' => 'required',
            'legal_name' => 'required',
            'short_description' => 'required|min:20|max:2500',
            'country' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'city' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'company_logo' => 'mimes:jpeg,png|max:1024|min:5',
            'telephone_1' => 'required|min:4',
            'zipcode' => 'required',
            'address_line_1' => 'required|min:5'
        ]);

        if ($v->fails()) {

        return false;

        } else {
        return true;
        }
   }
```